# Can I use a bootbox (bootstrap popup) in a click event html?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have to ask you if you really want to delete the selected item, I wanted to use bootbox.... This does not work!

```
<s:a onclick="return bootbox.confirm('Are you sure?')" action="deleteElement">
```

Answer (score 7):

> ***To the person, who voted to close this***, I don't understand what's unclear about this, as the question is super-clear, OP is not using the right syntax. The `bootbox.confirm()` or whatever, expects a callback function and this doesn't work in the traditional way.

You have to use a [`callback` function](http://bootboxjs.com/#examples) for this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm('Do you really wanna delete?', function (res) {
      if (res)
        location.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.example.com/" action="deleteElement" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
    $(".confirm").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm({
            message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'yes',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'no',
                    className: 'btn-danger'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result)
                    console.log('yes');
            }
        });
        
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://www.example.com/" action="deleteElement" class="btn btn-danger confirm">Delete</a>
```